# mod_rewrite only some rules work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file where everything works except one thing. The `example.com/home` redirects to `home.php`, and it is the same for files like `headsup_bet`. And if I clear the whole .htaccess `/home` is still redirecting to `home.php`.

I recently changed web host, and at the old one this worked. But not anymore.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Make sure site is using SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite urls
RewriteRule ^home$              index.php?page=home [L]
RewriteRule ^jackpot$           index.php?page=jackpot [L]
RewriteRule ^roulette$          index.php?page=roulette [L]
RewriteRule ^headsup$           index.php?page=headsup [L]
RewriteRule ^blender$           index.php?page=blender [L]
RewriteRule ^taxi$              index.php?page=taxi [L]
RewriteRule ^user$              index.php?page=user [L]
RewriteRule ^jackpots$          index.php?page=jackpots [L]
RewriteRule ^players$           index.php?page=players [L]
RewriteRule ^recruits$          index.php?page=recruits [L]
RewriteRule ^deposit$           index.php?page=deposit [L]
RewriteRule ^withdraw$          index.php?page=withdraw [L]
RewriteRule ^information$       index.php?page=information [L]
RewriteRule ^provably-fair$     index.php?page=provably-fair [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$             index.php?page=terms [L]
RewriteRule ^support$           index.php?page=support [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$           index.php?page=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^settings$          index.php?page=settings [L]
RewriteRule ^admin$             index.php?page=admin [L]
RewriteRule ^steamDown$         index.php?page=steamDown [L]
RewriteRule ^403$               index.php?page=403 [L]
RewriteRule ^404$               index.php?page=404 [L]

# Cache files 1 WEEK 
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>

# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

order allow,deny
allow from all

ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /403

php_flag display_errors 1
```

Comment: Can you provide an example URI that is, and one that _isn't_ working?

Comment: Is this even the right .htaccess file? Based on what you described there isn't a rule in there that does what you're saying. And nothing for a headsup_bet URI.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the two first rewrite-conditions work. And I have replace the ^home$ with ^(.*)$ and page=home to page=$1 but this affects other stuff like include in php-files, fonts, etc.

EDIT:
Link to example: 
https://csgospeed.com/home
https://csgospeed.com/index.php?page=home

Comment: ... so provide us with the thing that's not working...

Comment: Sorry, thought that was clear. Here is the rule:
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?page=home [L]

The same goes for all the ones with index.php

Comment: That rule _internally rewrites_ to `index.php`, whereas you state it _redirects_ to `home.php`? Is this the "one thing" that is not working?

Comment: Yes, except that the rule does internally rewrite (not redirect) to home.php (as I can understand).

Comment: @w3d is right. Your problem doesn't match up to what you've provided us / telling us.

Comment: What do you mean? I might not be good at explaining things but this is the problem. For me, it seems really weird.

Comment: @FredrikLivijn There is no rule you have provided here that would perform the redirect from `/home` to `/home.php`. Either this is not the full file, or there are other rules defined somewhere else

Comment: And as I said, if I clear the .htaccess-file, csgospeed.com/home still gives me the csgospeed.com/home.php when it should give me a 404

Comment: @arco444 this is indeed the full file. But it is hosted on a VPS that I cannot access since it is managed by the hosting provider. So, could there be more rules elsewhere? If that is the case, where do i find them?

And I have replace the `^home$` with `^(.*)$ and page=home to page=$1` and that actually makes it work, but this affects other stuff like include in php-files, fonts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole problem was really weird but it was solved with adding `Options -MultiViews`.

If anyone knows why, I'd be more than happy to learn.

Comment: Ah OK, so you do literally have a file called `home.php` in the document root in that case!? (Your mod_rewrite directives above do not do this rewrite, as mentioned in comments, all they do is pass the request on to `/index.php?page=home` - an _internal rewrite_, not an _external redirect_.) When `MultiViews` is enabled then when you specify a URL without an extension eg. `/home` then Apache will search for a matching file with an appropriate extension that would return the expected mime-type. In other words: `/home.htm`, `/home.html` or `/home.php` etc., and return that instead.